# Can we create a custom ROS2 message datatype?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, messages

I have a datatype called `alpha` which is based on float64. Now I want to create a custom ROS2 message which has this datatype instead of adding float64. Is there a way to do this?

My code would look like:

```
alpha number;
msg.data = number;
```

I want my msg type to be:

```
alpha data
```

Comment: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Single-Package-Define-And-Use-Interface.html

Comment: The tutorial still points to the use of existing datatypes. I want to to have my custom msg to be like this:

`alpha number`
Instead of
`float number`

Answer (score 1):

Custom ROS 2 messages are usually created using the basic message types which are supported by ROS 2. I don't think you can directly use your `Alpha` datatype to create a custom ROS 2 message.

However, you can use the basic datatypes which are provided to you by ROS 2 to recreate your `Alpha` datatype and then use **that** to create the custom datatype you want.

### Method

For example, you can create a ROS 2 package with a directory structure similar to the one below.

```
src
└── alpha_msgs
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    ├── msg
    │   ├── Alpha.msg
    │   └── AlphaArray.msg
    ├── package.xml
    └── src
```

Let's say you want to create an `Alpha` array datatype called `AlphaArray`. You can first define your alpha datatype from scratch.

```go
# Alpha.msg
float64 direction
float64 magnitude
```

Then you would use the custom `Alpha` datatype to create another custom array datatype such as `AlphaArray`.

```go
# AlphaArray.msg
Alpha[] data    # An array of Alpha.msg types
```

Then it's just a matter of specifying how your package should be built in the `CMakeLists.txt` and adding some dependencies to the `package.xml` file. The `CMakeLists.txt` would look something like this.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(alpha_msgs)

# some ROS 2 CMakeLists.txt template code

# find important dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

# find dependencies needed for your datatype
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)

# you can use this to get all msg files if you have many
set(MSGS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/msg")
file(GLOB ALPHA_MSGS RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${MSGS_DIR}/*.msg")


# generate code for message types
rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${ARUCO_MSGS}
    DEPENDENCIES std_msgs
)

# generate code for message types by manually
# specifying all the message types
# rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
#    msg/Alpha.msg
#    msg/AlphaArray.msg
#    DEPENDENCIES std_msgs
# )

# rest of ROS 2 CMakeLists.txt template code

ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)
ament_package()
```

And your `package.xml` would usually include the following lines.

```xml
<depend>rclcpp</depend>
<depend>std_msgs</depend>

<depend>rosidl_default_generators</depend>
<depend>rosidl_default_runtime</depend>

<member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
```

For more information, you can look at the [px4_msgs](https://github.com/PX4/px4_msgs) GitHub repository. It has a lot of custom message examples.

I hope this helps. If I have made any mistakes or if you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the detail information. Yeah I have a configuration which is the reason for me to use the custom datatype in ROS2 message. I will figure out if there is something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create custom message(alpha.msg) with the data type as needed.

   ```
   float32 alpha_message
   ```
2. Create custom message(beta.msg) where you want to import

   ```
   <package_name>/alpha beta_message
   ```

Comment: Please use code formatting , not block-quote formatting